# android 5.1 launcher crashed when I start a third app which has null exception

Tags: crash, launcher

I have a launcher app, it runs well on android 4.2.
When I transplant it to android 5.1， there is a question：

1.I found when I run a third app which has exception;

2.the third app crashed immediately and exit;

3.my lanucher crashed too;

logcat shows:
force to finishing the third app...
force to finishing my launcher...

and I use startActivity to run the third app.

sorry for my poor english, has anybody got any good ideas or ways for that?

Comment: it is only appears on android 5.1.1.